# Example of multivalued function that attains maximum when values form evenly spaced vector

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization, partial-derivative, nonlinear-optimization

I have four variables $x,y,z,w$, such that $x\ge1,w\le7, x\le y\le z\le w$.

I need to find a function that attains maximum when $x,y,z,w$ are evenly spaced on $[1,7]$, i.e. $(x,y,z,w)=\left(1,3,5,7\right)$ and minimum when all variables are equal.

$(4-(y-x))^2+(4-(z-x))^2+(4-(z-y))^2+(4-(w-x))^2+(4-(w-y))^2+(4-(w-z))^2$ is an example of such function, but depending on values $4-(y-x)$ can be either positive or negative. I need it to be either positive or negative.

Perhaps, somebody knows other examples of such functions or relevant literature.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is "it" in the sentence "I need it to be either positive or negative"?

Comment: Never mind. Just searching new functions, that will fit my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\,g\,$ be a strictly concave and strictly increasing function on $\,[\,0,6\,]\,$ such that $\,g(0)=0\,$.

Define $\,f : \left\{\, (x,y,z,w) \in [\,1,7\,]^4 \;\mid\; x \le y \le z \le w \,\right\} \to \mathbb{R}\,$ as: $$\,f(x,y,z,w) \;=\; g(y-x)+g(z-y)+g(w-z)$$

- $f$ is non-negative since so is $g\,$.
- $f(x,y,z,w) \gt 0$ if at least two consecutive variables are unequal since the respective $\,g(\cdot)\,$ term is strictly positive in that case, so $f(x,y,z,w)=0 \;\iff\; x=y=z=w\,$ i.e. the minimum of $\,0\,$ is attained when all variables are equal.
- It follows from [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality#Finite_form) that the maximum is attained when $y-x=z-y=w-z$ and it follows from monotonicity that it happens when $x=1,w=7$ i.e. at $\,(1,3,5,7)\,$:

$$\require{cancel}
\begin{align}
\displaystyle f(x,y,z,w) \;&=\; g(y-x)+g(z-y)+g(w-z) \\[5px]
 &\le\; 3 \cdot g\left(\frac{(\cancel{y}-x)+(\bcancel{z}-\cancel{y})+(w-\bcancel{z})}{3}\right) \;=\; 3 \cdot g\left(\frac{w-x}{3}\right) \\[5px]
 &\le 3 \cdot g\left(\frac{7-1}{3}\right) = 3\cdot g(2)
\end{align}
$$

An example could be $\,g(x) =\ln(1+x)\,$, but any $\,g\,$ satisfying the given conditions would work.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Can you clarify how it follows from Jensen's inequality conclusion about the maximum? Why above result is not applicable fro the function $g(y-x)+g(z-y)+g(w-z)+g\left(\frac{z-x}{2}\right)+g\left(\frac{w-x}{3}\right)+g\left(\frac{w-y}{2}\right)$ ?

Comment: @AndrewFount `Why above result is not applicable fro the function` The sum of the arguments of $\,g\,$ in that case doesn't give anything "nice" that could be used with Jensen's inequality.

Comment: @AndrewFount Jensen's inequality for a strictly convex function has that $$\frac{g(a)+g(b)+g(c)}{3} \le g\left(\frac{a+b+c}{3}\right)$$ with equality iff $\,a=b=c\,$. The answer above uses it for $\,a=y-x, b=z-y, c=w-z\,$ to show that $\,f(x,y,z,w) \le 3 \cdot g\left(\frac{w-x}{3}\right)\,$ with equality iff $\,y-x=z-y=w-z\,$. The last step uses that $\,g\,$ is strictly increasing to show that the maximum of $\,g\left(\frac{w-x}{3}\right)\,$ is attained when $\,w-x\,$ is maximum, which happens iff $\,w=7\,$ and $\,x=1\,$.

Comment: thank you for the response. But why this doesn't work for $g(y-x)+g(z-y)+g(w-z)+g\left(\frac{z-x}{2}\right)+g\left(\frac{w-x}{3}\right)+g\left(\frac{w-y}{2}\right)$ ?

Comment: @AndrewFount If you use it for your expression all you get is $$\le 6 \cdot g\left( \frac{1}{6}\left(y-x+z-y+w-z+\frac{z-x}{2}+\frac{w-x}{3}+\frac{w-y}{2}\right)\right)$$ which doesn't directly help you prove a maximum value.

Comment: but shouldn't be the maximum when $y-x=z-y=w-z=\frac{z-x}{2}=\frac{w-x}{3}=\frac{w-y}{2}$ ?

Comment: @AndrewFount In that case you get the equality in Jensen's, but the RHS still depends on *all* variables

$$
\le 6 \cdot g\left(\frac{ - 11 x - 3 y + 3 z + 11 w}{6}\right)
$$

That makes the next step of finding an upper bound $- 11 x - 3 y + 3 z + 11 w \le \,?$ trickier.

Comment: w-x<=6 and z-y<=6, so 11*6+3*6=84

Comment: @AndrewFount But that's precisely the problem there. You cannot attain *that* maximum at the same time with the equality case of Jensen's $y-x=z-y=w-z=\cdots\,$.

Comment: What about this? https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=maximize+11(w-x)%2B3(z-y),+w-z%3Dz-y,+z-y%3Dy-x,+x%3E%3D1,+w%3C%3D7

Comment: @AndrewFount That doesn't help, since you have two independent inequalities and you cannot "borrow" the equality conditions between the two. Fact is that with your construction you can prove that:

$$
g(y-x)+\dots \;\le\; 6 \,g(\dots) \;\le\; 6 \,g\left(\frac{84}{6}\right)
$$

But there is no case where *both* inequalities become equalities, so the RHS is just an upper bound, *not* a maximum.

P.S. This is getting too long for comments, sorry. If you think you have an alternative solution I suggest you post it as an answer and, as long as it holds, I'll be the first one to upvote.

Comment: That's the case. How do you prove that $3 \cdot g(2)$ is ever attained?

Comment: @AndrewFount $f(1,3,5,7)=g(3-1)+g(5-3)+g(7-5)=3 \cdot g(2)\,$.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you very much for you help.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the variables $(u_1, \dots, u_4) = (x+1, y-x, z-y, w-z)$. These are nonnegative and the maximum should be attained when they are equal.

There are lots of such functions of $u$, for example
$$\sum_{1\le i<j\le 4} (u_i-u_j)^2$$
or more generally
$$\sum_{1\le i<j\le 4} f(u_i-u_j)$$
for any $f$ that is minimized at $0$.

There are *symmetrization* theorems that show that certain quantities are maximized by equally spaced parameters; chapter 4 of [this survey](https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.01868) is one source of them.

Comment: This is great idea. I tried to apply it, but without success. What is x+1? Also, are you sure that function attains maximum at any point of the form (a,a,a,a)?

Comment: And evenly spaced vector should be the only minimum/maximum. Only f(a,a,a,a) can be maxima/minima.

Comment: @AndrewFount I guess $x+1$ came from the condition that when $x,y,z,w$ are evenly spaced on $[1,7]$, i.e. $(x,y,z,w)=\left(1,3,5,7\right)$ than $2=x+1=y-x=z-y=w-z$.