# Example of multivalued function (includes pairwise comparisons) that attains maximum when values form evenly spaced vector

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization, partial-derivative, nonlinear-optimization

Suppose, that I have 4 points $x,y,z,w$ (positions on the x-axis), such that $x\le y\le z\le w$.

I find pairwise distances between them: $y-x,z-x,w-x,z-y,w-y,w-z$. Distances should be less or equal to some constant $k$.

Is there a function that contains all pairwise distances and attains the only maximum when $x,y,z,w$ are evenly spaced on the interval $[1, k+1]$ and the only minima when all variables are equal?

The function shouldn't depend on $k$.

Comment: `a function that contains all pairwise distances` Those distances are not independent since, for example, $\,(z-x)=(z-y)+(y-x)\,$. How do you define `contains`, then? Would for example the function $\,z^2-2zx+x^2=(z-x)^2=(z-y)^2+2(z-y)(y-x)+(y-x)^2\,$ `contain` $\,(z-x)\,$, or $\,(z-y)\,$ *and* $\,(y-x)\,$, or both? Other than this new "*containment*" requirement, the question is virtually identical to your [previous one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2563087/291201), answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2576396/291201).

Comment: Contain without cancelling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\,g\,$ be a strictly concave and strictly increasing function on $\,[\,0,k\,]\,$ such that $\,g(0)=0\,$.

Define $\,f : \left\{\, (x,y,z,w) \in [\,1,k+1\,]^4 \;\mid\; x \le y \le z \le w \,\right\} \to \mathbb{R}\,$ as:

$$
\begin{align}
f(x,y,z,w) \;&=\; 2g(y-x)+g(z-y)+2g(w-z) \\[3px]
 &\quad +\;2 g\left(\frac{z-x}{2}\right) +  2 g\left(\frac{w-y}{2}\right) + \\[3px]
 &\quad +\;3 g\left(\frac{w-x}{3}\right)
\end{align}
$$

- $\,f\,$ is non-negative since so is $\,g\,$.
- $\,f(x,y,z,w) \gt 0\,$ if at least one of the arguments passed into $\,g\,$ is non-zero, since the respective $\,g(\cdot)\,$ term is strictly positive in that case, so $f(x,y,z,w)=0$ iff all arguments are zero $\;\iff\; x=y=z=w\,$ i.e. the minimum of $\,0\,$ is attained when all variables are equal.
- It follows from [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality#Finite_form) that the maximum for a fixed total span $\,w-x\,$ is attained when $y-x$ $=z-y$ $=w-z$ $\displaystyle=\frac{z-x}{2}$ $\displaystyle=\frac{w-y}{2}$ $\displaystyle=\frac{w-x}{3}$ which happens iff the values are evenly spaced, and it follows from monotonicity that the absolute maximum is attained when $x=1,w=k+1$ i.e. at $\displaystyle\,\left(1,\frac{k+3}{3},\frac{2k+3}{3},k+1\right)\,$:

$$\require{cancel}
\begin{align}
\displaystyle
f(x,y,z,w) \;&=\; 2g(y-x)+g(z-y)+2g(w-z) + 2 g\left(\frac{z-x}{2}\right) + 2 g\left(\frac{w-y}{2}\right) +\;3 g\left(\frac{w-x}{3}\right) \\[5px]
 &\le\; 12 \cdot g\left(\frac{2(y-x)+(z-y)+2(w-z)+2 \cfrac{z-x}{2}+2 \cfrac{w-y}{2}+3 \cfrac{w-x}{3}}{12}\right) \\[5px]
 &=\; 12 \cdot g\left(\frac{4(w-x)}{12}\right) \\[5px]
 &\le 12 \cdot g\left(\frac{(k+\bcancel{1})-\bcancel{1}}{3}\right) \\[5px]
 &= 12 \cdot g\left(\frac{k}{3}\right)
\end{align}
$$

An example could be $\,g(x) =\ln(1+x)\,$, but any $\,g\,$ satisfying the given conditions would work.

---

[ *EDIT* ]  A more general solution along the same line can be constructed from the identity:

$$
\small a (y - x) + b (z - y) + c (w - z) + (c - b) (z - x) + (a - b) (w - y) + (p - a + b - c) (w - x) \;=\; p(w-x)
$$

Choose $\,0 \le b \le a,c\,$ and $\,p \ge a-b+c\,$ so that all coefficients are positive. Then the function defined below satisfies the posed requirements:

$$
\begin{align}
f(x,y,z,w) \;&=\; a\cdot g(y-x)+ b \cdot g(z-y)+ c \cdot g(w-z) \\[3px]
&\quad + 2(c-b) \cdot g\left(\frac{z-x}{2}\right) + 2(a-b) \cdot g\left(\frac{w-y}{2}\right) \\[3px]
 &\quad + 3(p-a+b-c) \cdot g\left(\frac{w-x}{3}\right)
\end{align}
$$

The proof goes just like before, and the maximum is $\displaystyle\,3p \cdot g\left(\frac{k}{3}\right)\,$.

The particular case above corresponds to $b=1, a=c=2, p=4\,$, and the case used in [this related answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2576396/291201) corresponds to $a=b=c=p=1\,$.

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I was looking for? How will this change if I have more than 4 variables?

Comment: @AndrewFount Glad it helped. It should work similarly for more variables. First step would be to establish an equivalent identity $\,\sum_{1 \le i \lt j \le n} a_{ij}(x_j-x_i) = p(x_n-x_1)\,$ with $\,a_{ij}, p \ge 0\,$. I don't have a closed form offhand, but pretty sure one can be found. Then, the function $\,f(x) = \sum_{1 \le i \lt j \le n} a_{ij}(j-i) \cdot g\left(\frac{x_j-x_i}{j-i}\right)\,$ would posess all the required properties.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if there are no further restrictions then such a function does exist. Let $$d_1=y-x,\quad d_2=z-y,\quad d_3=w-z,$$
$$\alpha=\begin{cases} d_1+1&\text{if }d_1=d_2=d_3,\\
0& \text{otherwise},\\
\end{cases}$$
and
$$f(x,y,z,w)=\begin{cases}\alpha & \text{if }\alpha>1,\\
1&\text{if }\alpha=0,\\
0&\text{if }\alpha=1.  \end{cases}$$

Comment: Where is z-x, w-x, w-y?

Comment: @AndrewFount the domain restriction involving them can't be stated explicitly without mentioning $k$.